# I have to create a html table and form like the one given in the picture

Tags: html, css

I have to recreate this table in HTML using CSS.

[image: html table]

This is what I have so far and it does look like the one in the picture but I feel like something's missing. I feel like the borders look different or something, I really don't know but something isn't right. Can someone please help me figure it out?

```css
table {
  border: solid 1px;
  border-spacing: 4px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif
}

td {
  background-color: #00ccff;
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.first-column {
  padding-right: 140px;
  padding-left: 11px;
}

.second-column {
  padding-left: 11px;
}

.table-heading {
  background-color: #ffffa9;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ec0d01;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

select {
  background-color: #cdffcc;
  width: 500px;
}

input[type="file"] {
  background-color: #cdffcc;
}

input[type="text"] {
  background-color: #cdffcc;
  width: 500px;
}

input[type="password"] {
  background-color: #cdffcc;
  width: 500px;
}

.input-file {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  background-color: #cdffcc;
}

textarea {
  background-color: #cdffcc;
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
}

button {
  background-color: #cdffcc;
  /* blue */
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  width: 250px;
}

.buttons {
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 13px;
  padding-left: 13px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="table-heading" colspan="2">User Form</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="table-body">
        <tr>
          <td class="first-column">Enter Name</td>
          <td class="second-column"><input type="text" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="first-column">Enter Password</td>
          <td class="second-column"><input type="password" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="first-column">Enter Address</td>
          <td class="second-column"><textarea name="email" cols="40" rows="3">        </textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="first-column">Select Game</td>
          <td class="second-column">
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox">Hockey<br>
              <input type="checkbox">Football<br>
              <input type="checkbox">Badminton<br>
              <input type="checkbox">Cricket<br>
              <input type="checkbox">Volleyball<br>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="first-column">Gender</td>
          <td class="second-column">
            <div>
              <input type="radio" name="gender">Male
              <input type="radio" name="gender">Female
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="first-column">Select your age</td>
          <td class="second-column">
            <div class="age-select">
              <select>
                <option value="" disabled selected hidden>select</option>
                <option value="">18-24</option>
                <option value="">25-34</option>
                <option value="">35-44</option>
                <option value="">45-59</option>
                <option value="">60+</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="input-file" colspan="2"><input type="file"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <div class="buttons">
              <button>Click Me</button>
              <button type="reset">Reset</button>
              <button>Submit Form</button>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: *Exactly* like that? With all the weird borders and bad colors?

Comment: @ceejayoz yes, like that.

Comment: @DavidThomas it's for a school project.